# How do I get JUnit to be consistent when timing out?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, concurrency, junit

JUnit `@Test`s have the useful ability to specify a `timeout` argument so that a poorly written program gets killed automatically if it takes longer than `timeout` seconds. The problem is this uses *clock* time instead of *CPU* time - so a test will actually run for different amounts of time between runs. For example, a test might run for 1.901 or 1.894 seconds for a 2 second timeout, depending on what other jobs are running on the CPU at the same time.

Can I specify a timeout or similar that would be consistent across runs? (Extensions to this question include: consistent across machines, etc)

Comment: On different machines i think not. Your code will defenetly need a different amout of time depending on cpu+ram etc.

Comment: Thats more or less what I thought. But what about consistent across runs on the same machine?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? It should take exactly 1.8942451 seconds to execute this code, would be, hm, useless?

Comment: @Ishtar I have no clue what you just said.

Comment: What is the real problem here? Why do you care about 0.007 of a second? Both the values specified above are under the 2s time out, and if 2s is not enough, give the test an extra second or rewrite it.

Comment: Or is it the timeout that is failing early? Give it three seconds and/or look at the test in question.

Comment: No, the point is that `otherThread.join(long millis)` is not deterministic: 1) the current thread isn't guaranteed to sleep for `millis` time and 2) the `otherThread` will actually run for different amounts of (CPU) time, depending on other processes running on the machine.

Comment: "Can I specify a timeout or similar that would be consistent across runs?" Why would you need that? What are you testing? You're right about `join`, but why would you care? I'm missing something here... Could you explain why you need a CPU time clock?

Comment: I want timeouts to be consistent across runs because thats useful for unit testing? I don't care how, but I assume that CPU time clock will probably have to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best approach is to set the JUnit timeout to ~2-3x your required timeout and do your own benchmarking using a [`ThreadMXBean`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) to measure CPU time if available.  You can then `fail` if you've exceeded your timeout.

Comment: ou could implement your own junit timeout based on CPU time drawn from the mbean... oooh, I might do that :D

Comment: I tried that, and it almost works. Except: 1) the 2-3x is still just a guess and 2) `Thread.sleep()` doesn't increase CPU time but does make it take more time ( thus a program that sleeped for 1.5 seconds would pass a unit test that was supposed to timeout after 1 second ).